# Changing Accordion title on expand/collapse changing more than one span

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get an text in an accordion title to change when it is expanded and collapsed.
It works except when I have another accordion inside then it changes both on collapse. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mwvuH/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-body").on("show",function(event){
    $('span', $(this).prev()).text('-');
  });
  $(".accordion-body").on("hide",function(event){
    $('span', $(this)).text('+');
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <div class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFive">
        Title
        <a href="#collapseFive"><span class="pull-right">+</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseFive" class="accordion-body collapse out">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
      Inside
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <div class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSix">
            Inside Title
            <a href="#collapseSix"><span class="pull-right">+</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseSix" class="accordion-body collapse out">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Inside Inside
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because click event on child bubbles up and trigger's parent's click event too. So stop Propagation of event and try this way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-body").on("show",function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
     $('span', $(this).siblings('.accordion-heading')).text('-');
  });
  $(".accordion-body").on("hide",function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
    $('span', $(this).siblings('.accordion-heading')).text('+');
  });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnWwN/)

BTW if you are using event only for toggling text you could combine them to one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-body").on("show hide",function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();

      $('span', $(this).siblings('.accordion-heading')).text(function(){
          return this.innerHTML === '+' ? '-' : '+';
      });
  });

});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhZCq/)

Comment: This is breaking other accordions on the page.

Comment: do you know what is breaking? do you have the issue replicable in a fiddle?

Comment: I have another span in a title. I am changing the color of a word. And it changes that word on click. http://jsfiddle.net/PYkjS/1/

Comment: @Siecje here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/bYQFX/ Next tmioe please post your complete sample html.